# How to prevent iPad Modal that contain UIWebView to rotate to portrait

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, rotation, modal-dialog

I have application that is only landscape with no other orentation supported. 
But when I open modal view (modal contains `UIWebView ([printView setView:webView])`) it rotates the device to portrait.

The content stays in landscape view only iPad orientation. I mean the statusbar is rotated like it's in portrait. So I want no rotation at all, just to stay in landscape.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Problem was in viewController that was programaticly created.
Solution is to create viewControler and in .m file force landscape orentation.